# How to use the GetPublishedSocialContent function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to figure out the [**GetPublishedSocialContent()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/GetPublishedSocialContent.htm) function.

Anyone know how to use it?

I can add a social sharing region and generate the links, so I'd think the `GetPublishedSocialContent()` would return the content inside the sharing region, but it doesn't.

```
<!-- RegionStart[contentslot:"social1", title:"Join Today"] -->
<a href="https://example.com/join">Join Today!</a>
<!-- RegionEnd[contentslot:"social1"] -->

<br><br><a href="%%=GetSocialPublishURLByName('Facebook','social1')=%%">Share on Facebook</a>
<br><a href="%%=GetSocialPublishURLByName('Twitter','social1')=%%">Share on Twitter</a>

<br><br>%%=GetPublishedSocialContent('social1')=%%
```

I get this error instead:

```
An error occurred when attempting to evaluate an 
GetPublishedSocialContent function call.  
See inner exception for details.

ExactTarget.OMM.InvalidFunctionParameterException:  
  Invalid value specified for function parameter.
  Function Name: GetPublishedSocialContent
  Parameter Name: PublishedSocialContentID
  Parameter Ordinal: 1
  Parameter Type: Numeric
  Submitted Value: social1
  ClientID: XXXXXXXX
  JobID: 0
  ListID: 0
  BatchID: 0
  SubcriberID: 0
  Data Source Type: List
Source:  OMMCommon
```

Based on the error, I should be specifying the `Region ID` as a number, not a string as shown in the example on the wiki:

```
GetPublishedSocialContent("SocialRegion1")
```

My next thought was to create a Content Area and reference that, but I get the same error.

It's not a Content Builder asset thing either.  Tried the ID from one of those.  Same error.

Where does this `Region ID` come from?

Answer (score 2):

This link might help you. Refer to chapter 19. I don't have social studio in my instance but this document is good

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/206/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/api_social.pdf#page181

Comment: I thought it might be Ad Studio related.  I have an old ExactTarget AMPScript reference that includes details on the function, which gave pause.  I guess I'll add a network to my demo Ad Studio and see if I can track down a RegionID.